# Runtime compiler is not loaded not works by AoT

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I decide to improve my site performance with angular 2 AoT compiler.
As some requirements issue, i need loading my components dynamically in my ng2 app, when i start to build my app with AoT compiler, everythings goes well, but if i open the url, i got an error: "Runtime compiler is not loaded", after i doing some researches on the Internet, it's look like that Aot could not works with runtime compiler defaultly. Is there any workaround? Any input will be appreciated.
[issue 12885](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12885) on Github.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11780 Seems like a mixed system is currently not supported

Comment: can i use derectives replace components for archiving goals

Comment: Directives are just components without a view. I don't know what your goals are. Perhaps adding components dynamically like used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 works for you.